# Can't receive message after reconnecting Smack

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, openfire, smack

I'm developing a chat application using server side as OpenFire 3.9.3 and client as Smack 4.2.

***My question:***

1. If user turn off WIFI/mobile data then reconnecting action will be occurring. That's fine. But OpenFire session is showing it as online during client reconnecting. Is it the normal behavior?
2. While the user1 is reconnecting the process and if user2 sends the message to user1 and if those messages are not delivered to user1 after the reconnection was successful, is there any way to get those message?

   The period of the reconnecting process time is considered as online in OpenFire, therefore those messages are not stored in the offline manager.

   Please provide me with some ideas as to receive the messages after reconnecting Smack.

Comment: Have you enabled logging history and Archive settings in openfire server?

Comment: Thanks for reply..yes enabled..I could able to see those message in server side. But how to retrieve from client side. and how to differ which one not delivered.

Comment: So I would give you an instance of how to set a connection function after you login

Comment: u got this fixed ??

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is the comment I made above on how you can set a listener after you login:

```
public void setConnection() {
        if (connection != null) {
            // Add a packet listener to get messages sent to us
            PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
            connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
                @Override
                public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                    Message m = (Message) packet;
                    if (m.getBody() != null) {
                        String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(m
                                .getFrom());

                        logs.append("\n");
                        logs.append(fromName + ":  " + m.getBody());
                        logs.append("\n");

                    }
                }
            }, filter);
        }

    }
```

If you put a method like this after in your login listener or however you login, you would get all offline messages.

Comment: Also try checking Openfire  Server > Server settings > offline messages to see if your settings are good.

Comment: stanzalistener has been implemented after login only.  and offlineManager fine in server side. After reconnecting successful I have called offlineManager which returned the list with zero..as well as packetlistener not returns those message that sender sent message during receiver reconnecting process. Ex: user1 sent the messages during user2 in reconnecting process..

Comment: also question for you, do you get offline messages when the situation is normal (i.e. no network re-connection) ?  If you are talking network issues, then I guess its beyond the settings you have mentioned, then try setting your stanzas on connect action instead of login,